# ForeignKey model query filter

Tags: django, django-models, filtering

Using filter(), how do I get the foreign key property 'recipient' of the current authenticated user ?

Models.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'recipient',null = True)
    sender = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser,related_name = 'messages')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, blank = True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default = True) 

class CustomUser(User):
   user_bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
           return self.username
```

Views.py:

```
### Inbox list class
class InboxListView(ListView):
'''
This view lets the user view all the messages created in a list
'''
model = Message# [Message,SafeTransaction] # I want to be able to draw from two models/objects #
template_name = "myInbox/inbox.html"
paginate_by = 5

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InboxListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['message_list'] = Message.objects.filter(recipient=CustomUser.SOMETHING_idk)#INCORRECT FILTRATION, FIX ASAP!!!!!!!!!!!!!#
    context['now'] = timezone.now()
    context['safeTransaction_list'] = SafeTransaction.objects.all()
    return context
```

Specifically this line is what I need puzzled out :

`context['message_list']=Message.objects.filter(recipient=CustomUser.SOMETHING_idk)`

What can I put as the filter parameter for a specific message recipient ?
I tried something along the lines of CustomUser or CustomUser.pk, or request.authenticated_as_the_thing_I_want_specifically. etcetera.

I seem to be a bit lost with it.

any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: So you use `CustomUser` as your authentication user?

Comment: What is the type of `self.request.user`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've created a custom auth user model? Assuming that's been setup correctly you should be able to do the following:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InboxListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'message_list': Message.objects.filter(recipient=self.request.user),
        'now': timezone.now(),
        'safeTransactionList': SafeTransaction.objects.all(),
    })
    return context
```

Some additional things of note:

- `now` is available as a django template tag. You can `{% now %}` in your template code.
- With the way the Django ORM works you would be able to use the following in your template code `{% for message in request.user.recipient.all %}` or `{% for message in request.user.messages.all %}` instead of making the ORM call in `get_context_data` to iterate over `message_list` for the logged in user.

Comment: using your systanx of contex.update({})

Would my method finally look like this instead :  https://pastebin.com/embed_js/XYXqXaZz 
?

Comment: @timi95 I've updated my answer for a complete `get_context_data`